# GWT: how can I change browser tab name?

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, gwt, browser

I know that to change the name of the tab in which browser opens the site I need to to change the title tag in the html file.

But in GWT the things are a bit different: each new place uses the same html file, so the browser tab's name will be the same for all the places.

1. How can I specify a name for each of my places?
2. This idea above do not work in IE 9. In IE 9 I see www.my-site.com/#my-place-name: name of the browser tab displayed instead of the contents of title tag. How can I make it work for IE  too?

Comment: Any chance IE9 is trying to load IE8 version of your GWT app. Check whether your gwt module has ie9 user agent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alter the title of the page with the following code

```
Window.setTitle("My Place Name");
```

Do notice that the place who call this the latest will set its title.

Comment: I Think the question already mentions the use of title tag. He is querying about ie9 specific issue.

Comment: No @SachinShekharR, the OP specifically asks how to change the title dynamically depending on the current place in the app. It *also* asks about IE9, but maybe that'd be fixed by that call to `setTitle` (TBH, I never bothered updating the title)

Comment: This is very useful for browser history if a user wants to jump a few places back (i.e. to a specific product page, artist page, etc.) or find a place in browser history. Otherwise a browser displays every place in your app with exactly the  same title.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the page title (e.g "Tab Name") by a call to a static function in GWT:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
...
public static void setBrowserWindowTitle (String newTitle) {
    if (Document.get() != null) {
        Document.get().setTitle (newTitle);
    }
}
```